# How to block the main Android thread until an Intent is received?

Tags: android, multithreading, process

I would like to block the execution of an application (let say A) until another application (let say B) sends an Intent. I know that blocking a thread with an infinite loop is not good but I really need to guarantee, for security reasons, that the code of A is not executed until an Intent is received. Just before blocking the application A, I start another application B using an Intent. This way, application A would have chances to survive until B finishes.  For this purpose, I currently wrote a blocking loop such as:

```
 context.startActivity(message); // starting app B

 // Blocking A
 while (condition) // waits an authorization from B
 { 
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    // some checks can be done here to modify the condition evaluation
    // for example, check the Intents received from B
 }
 // (Secured zone) 
 // Some code that should not be executed before that the condition is true
```

I tried a lot of solutions to check the Intent reception:

- using a `broadcastreceiver` is not possible, as the main thread will never have a chance to process the received Intent
- using a binding service to another applications to get the information: again, the `onConnectedService` method will not be called because the main thread will not process the event.
- using a second independent process that would be notified of the incoming Intent: this works well.The second process is notified but it cannot inform the main thread that somethings happened !
- using a second Thread to check received Intents, binding service to B: no way, the second Thread is not in charge of processing messages.

Maybe I am missing a simple solution but I start to think that I am trying to do something that is really contradictory with Android's philosophy...

Edit: another constraint is that the "secured zone" part of the code cannot be moved elsewhere in my program...

Comment: How do you know when Intent is received..?

Comment: I think you should find another way of preventing your code to be run. It is never a good idea to lock the main thread, both of user interaction, and because the system will most likely think the activity is frozen and ask the user if he/she wants to shut it down.

Comment: For example, I can capture the Intent using a BroadcastReceiver that executes the onReceive method in a second process if I put in the manifest: <receiver android:name="reporter.ReporterReceiver"  android:process=":p2">

Comment: I agree with Jave. I should not do that, and if I close app B (then returning to app A), the system waits a little that it exits my loop and finally decides to kill my app. But, it does not matter for me, because I prefer that the app crashes and does not execute the rest of the code for security reasons. If the user stays in app B, app A survives and is not killed...

Answer (score 0):

A Thread.sleep() in the main thread is not a good idea. 
Have you tried overriding the onNewIntent() method in activity A in order to handle intents sent by activity B ?

Comment: I did not tried that but my constraint is that I want to avoid the execution of the remaining code of application A. App B sends an authorization for app A that is allowed to execute the rest of the code. If I do not block the main thread, I am sure I will successfully catch the Intent from B, but I will violate my constraint...

Comment: You should never block the main thread this way. My best advice would be to rethink your approach. May be use worker threads (AsyncTask class) to run tasks in the background.

Answer (score 0):

It think you should use another approach :
Run appA and inside appA, the first thing you should do is run appB and wait till its result.
When you get you results, continue run appA.

Pseudo code as i see it:

```
AppA()
{
  run app B;
  if (b return needed result)
  {
    rest of code of AppA...
    ....
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I try to do. But it is impossible to wait for B's result because both app A and B will execute in concurrency. Even using a call to startActivityForResult() will not block because the result is obtained asynchronously when Android calls onActivityResult().

Answer (score 0):

I found an ugly way of solving my issue. After pausing app A, app A is waiting the intent from B that is executed in a different process. Then, when this process receives the message from B, it writes the information into a file. The main thread of A thas is blocked into the loop, reads periodically the file. When the file contains the expected information, the condition becomes false and the thread is unblocked.

In details, it gives:

Into app A:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);

context.startActivity(message); // starting app B

// Blocking A
while (!auth) // waits an authorization from B
{ 

try {
  FileInputStream fIn = c.openFileInput("authorization.txt");
  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
  char buf[] = new char[1];
  isr.read(buf);
  String res = new String(buf);
  isr.close();

  if (res.equals("1"))
  {
  auth = true;
  System.out.println("READ OK");
  }
}
```

In app A, a broadcast receiver should be declared in the manifest with the android:process tag ":p2":

```
<receiver android:name="reporter.ReporterReceiver"  android:process=":p2">
  <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="andro.jf.reporterResponse" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and the receiver should be:

```
public class ReporterReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();

    System.out.println("ANSWER RECEIVED");

    if (extra != null)
    {
    String auth = extra.getString("authorization");
    //Reporter.authorization = contact;

    // Write the string to the file
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = context.openFileOutput("authorization.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
        osw.write(auth);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
}
```

I know, this is ugly... but it works, at least in the emulator.